# I need to optimize this MYSQL query

Tags: mysql, sql, count, subquery, mysql-workbench

```
SELECT COUNT(student_id) AS count 
FROM student_details 
WHERE STATUS='REGISTER'
    AND student_id NOT IN (
        SELECT student_id FROM student_details  WHERE STATUS='CANCEL'
    )
    AND registered_on< '2020-10-15 00:00:00'
```

I have tried NOT EXIST but didn't get expected result

```
SELECT COUNT(DISTINCT  S.student_id) AS ren 
FROM student_details S
WHERE 
    S.status = 'REGISTER'
    AND S.registered_on < '2020-10-15 00:00:00'
    AND NOT EXISTS ( 
        SELECT 1 
        FROM  student_details S1 
        WHERE S.student_id = S1.student_id AND S1.status = 'CANCEL'
    )
```

can't do index  since duplicate entries of student_id,status are valid entries,Need to reduce execution time since the table has large number of data.

Comment: WHat about indexes?

Comment: Can you add a DESCRIBE with your question?

Comment: Please edit the question and add output of `show create table student_details` and `show create table subscription` and `explain SELECT COUNT(...rest of your original query`  (not `describe`, it isn't helpful enough.)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can try query with JOIN condition:

```
SELECT COUNT(student_details.student_id) AS count 
FROM student_details 
LEFT JOIN subscription 
    ON subscription.student_id = student_details.student_id AND subscription.status = 'CANCEL'
WHERE 
    student_details.status='REGISTER'
    AND subscription.status IS NULL
    AND registered_on< '2020-10-15 00:00:00';
```

Here the fiddle [SQLize.online](https://sqlize.online/?phpses=null&sqlses=103eaff328b5bce2c9283b46c54d28ee&php_version=null&sql_version=mysql80)

**Sure that your tables have index on student_id field. Since you filter by status field, so index on this field can improve the query performance**

Comment: Thank you all for your inputs..Indexing did the job.

Answer (score 2):

If you want something equivalent to the first query with `not exists`, the logic is:

```
SELECT COUNT(*) AS ren 
FROM student_details sd
WHERE 
    sd.status = 'REGISTER'
    AND sd.registered_on < '2020-10-15 00:00:00'
    AND NOT EXISTS (SELECT 1 FROM  subscription s WHERE s.student_id = sd.student_id AND s.status = 'CANCEL')
```

That is:

- The subquery should address table `subscription`, not `student_details`.
- You don't want `count(distinct ...)` - the outcome might be just the same, if `student_id` is a unique key in `student_details`, but you did not tell. I used `count(*)`, which assumes that `student_id` is not `null`able.

This query would take advantage of an index on `subscription(student_id, status)`.

Comment: Thanks for your input, But it's taking long time to process, I need to optimize the query to reduce the time.

Comment: @SenthilKumar: do you have the recommended index in place?

Comment: Thank you for your inputs..Indexing did the job